# WCF: Channel using binding with streaming does not fault when server does not exist

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-binding

I'm writing a mini-framework to aid with client-server connections using WCF, and I've encountered unexpected behavior.

If a client opens a channel to a service that is not available, and then makes a method call vis-a-vis that service, the resulting behavior differs depending on whether or not the binding for the channel has transferMode set to "Streaming".

If the binding is not set to streaming and the service is unavailable, WCF immediately raises the ICommunicationObject.Faulted event. On the other hand, if it is, WCF raises the ICommunicationObject.Opened event.

Can anyone explain the reason for this difference in behavior? Seems pretty odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've been researching this for several hours and believe that I have an answer (I'll mark this as the answer eventually if no one has a better answer).

According to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742%28VS.90%29.aspx) on msdn, "All streaming calls are made through a single channel (**the datagram channel**) that does not support sessions even if the binding being used is configured to use sessions." (Note the bolded text.) Although it's not so clear to me what it means to be using a datagram channel over a TCP/IP protocol, I'll take it at face-value.

So, [another msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733912%28VS.90%29.aspx), states that "A datagram channel is a channel in which all messages are uncorrelated. With a datagram channel, if an input or output operation fails, the next operation is typically unaffected, and the same channel can be reused. Because of this, datagram channels typically do not fault."

So, apparently, streaming channels simply do not fault. Although trying to send a message over the channel throws a socket exception (because if the service is unavailable obviously the socket cannot be opened), as far as WCF is concerned, this does not mean that the state of the channel is faulted. I.e., you can still send another message over the same channel and, if the service becomes available, the message might transfer successfully.

It still seems odd to me though, that a channel's state is considered to be open when the socket connection was never made. So I'd still be glad to hear an explanation if someone has a deeper understanding of this.

Comment: Datagram implies that UDP is being used (not TCP), which is a connectionless protocol; i.e. you have no way of telling the state of the connection. (See the MEP section in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751494.aspx.) So, what you say makes sense -- I'm guessing they use UDP for streaming to avoid the handshaking overhead required for TCP et al., though it seems bad for them to do this with a binding that requests a session. (I'm new to this stuff myself, but I think this is right.)

Comment: I'm not sure this is right. Even the article you posted discusses UDP as an option for extending WCF, not as anything built in to WCF. And I have a bit of a hard time believing that an explicit TCP binding configuration would implicitly use UDP as the transport channel. Of course, you never know :)